# Android 4.0.1 breaks WebView HTML 5 local storage?

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile, webview, local-storage

I have a simple html5 test page which uses LocalStorage to display / save  / redisplay a piece of data.

This code works perfectly in Android 2.3.x but *logs* an exception in 4.0.1 on line 18 of the html which is the frist `localStorage.getItem()` call and at this point the JS stops.

Exception: `Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18 at /data/data/my.app.name/app_htmlData:18`
I've also tried setting the database path to `getCacheDir()` with the same result.

```
String htmlContent = "HTML content listed below";    
File sharedDir = getActivity().getDir("htmlData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
WebView browser = (WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.wvBrowser);

browser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
    public void onExceededDatabaseQuota(String url, String databaseIdentifier, long  currentQuota, long estimatedSize,   long totalUsedQuota, WebStorage.QuotaUpdater quotaUpdater) { 
            quotaUpdater.updateQuota(estimatedSize * 2); 
        }
    });       
browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){

        view.loadUrl("javascript:doTest()");

    });

browser.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
browser.getSettings().setDatabasePath(sharedDir.getPath());
browser.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
browser.loadDataWithBaseURL(mSharedDir.getPath(), 
            htmlContent, 
            "text/html", 
            "utf-8", 
            null);
```

The HTML that the page is rendering is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Simple localStorage test</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function doTest() {
            $('#stuff').append('<p>reading</p>');
            var item = read();

            $('#stuff').append('<p>writing</p>');
            localStorage['bar'] = new Date().toUTCString();

            $('#stuff').append('<p>&nbsp;</p><p>reading again</p>');
            read();
        }
        function read() {
            var item = localStorage.getItem('bar');
            if (item == null || (item == undefined)) {
                item = '';
            }
            $('#stuff').append('<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;item: ' + item + '</p>');

         return item;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>-Simple localStorage test-</p>
    <div id="stuff"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Source available [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9938553/localstorage_bug.zip)

Comment: What is the exception that gets logged?

Comment: Sorry, that would be useful - added to question

Comment: That's odd. If you have a complete sample project you could package up and upload someplace, I'd like to take a look at it.

Comment: Done, I noticed that in the 4.0 change logs lurks this: "WebKit updated to version 534.30"

Comment: I see what you're seeing, and I don't have an explanation, other than this issue: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16175

Comment: Thanks for looking, good to know it's not just me... I think.

Comment: @MrChaz My own code works on 4.0.3 - do you know if your problem was specific to 4.0.1 or it exists on 4.0.3+ ?

Comment: @zaf 4.1 and upwards this issue seems to be gone in my apps. 4.0.3 doesnt work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Via some discussion with a Google engineer it seems that they've made the decision that the file:// scheme is insecure.

A work around for this is to do the following

```
browser.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://www.example.com", 
            htmlContent, 
            "text/html", 
            "utf-8", 
            null);
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot for the answer, it has also solved my queries of Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18:2.

Answer (score 4):

For android versions less than 4.4, loading data into a webview with a file scheme as a directory:

```
browser.loadDataWithBaseUrl("file:///android_asset/", html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

wont work with localStorage. If I add a filename it does work on older OS versions

```
browser.loadDataWithBaseUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html", html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: Unbelievable...
On my situation, the app is using API 12, to run since Android 3.1 that do not has setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379392/jquery-mobile-not-working-in-webview-when-loading-from-local-assets) to set to true, so, blank page on 4.2. With that now it's all ok.