# How to keep SQLite queries in seperate text files and access them in Android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, text

I want to keep database creation queries and data accessing queries in text file format (those text files will be in a folder like "res" folder) and access them from android.

Let's say I want to execute the createDB() query, then I should be able to call by the relevant text file name and query should be executed.

I searched the internet and couldn't end up with a suitable tutorial or solution. So I am seeking some idea/solution or at least a good tutorial which satisfy my requirement.

Comment: you can also store Queries in **strings.xml**

Comment: just use CONSTANTS for the DDL and Query statements...

Comment: in strings.xml, or in a separate strings file named queries.xml

Comment: Thanks gtumca-MAC and Christine.can you please explain bit about how to do it with xml and/or how should I call the xml?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you want to do that but this is how you can do it:

1) Put those files in `assets` folder
2) You can open them like this:

```
InputStream input = context.getAssets().open("example.xml");
```

Comment: Is `fileName` a string or a `File`?

Comment: It is a `String`, only the file name without path; for example: "example.xml"

Comment: Is it prefixed with `file:///`?

Comment: OK, I was just making sure. Because apparently accessing files with `file:///` crashes your app on ICS and I was wondering if you knew how to fix that because I could never figure it out :P

Comment: i.e. this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390985/android-4-0-1-breaks-webview-html-5-local-storage