# Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18 in webview android?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

i am working with android webview and displaying webpages inside it .So the webpages are calling MathJax.js file but it is showing error to load the file ,the error is like-

Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18 at file:///mnt/sdcard/Mathsmethod/Pages/mathjax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_SVG,local/local:29

suggest me any solution so that i 'll able to solve the issue programmatically

Comment: Did you give the External_Storage permission in manifest file

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: these permission i have given for storage

Comment: any another permission required??

Comment: can you post your java code

Comment: How did you access a SdCard Path from your class file

Comment: w.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///" + base_url+ "/Pages/", Stringdataofhtml, "text/html", "utf-8",null);

Comment: I am getting a similar error using MathJax in an Android web view. Did you figure it out? In my case, I am adding my local copy of MathJax in the Android Assets, so I am not using the sdcard.

Comment: not yet but if the mathjax is at server side it is working perfectly

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390985/android-4-0-1-breaks-webview-html-5-local-storage