# jQuery Mobile not working in WebView when loading from local assets

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, webview

I am trying to render in my Android app a page created using jQueryMobile, but I need to do it in a webView, in an offline state.

For that purpose, I started copying the index.html of my page and taking all the required assets straight to the internal storage of my device. I then loaded it up typing `file:///sdcard/index.html` in both the internal browser of my device and the Chrome app, and the website showed up just fine, with jQuery styles and all.

Then I move in to my app, where I have a webView, and that's where I actually need to render the aforementioned page. I load the page using `loadDataWithBaseURL()` (because that's what I ultimately need to do) like this:

```
loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/web/", html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

I keep all my assets in the web directory of my assets folder.

The problem is, if I load the page without the assets reference (just normally calling `loadUrl`) it loads but obviously without styling or functionality. When I put the assets reference calling `loadDataWithBaseURL` it IS indeed reading the asset reference properly but the rendering is stuck with jqueryMobile's spinning wheel and the page never actually loads. This is what I see:

[image]

So to sum it up:

- I have created a website using jQuery Mobile. It's just a simple html
  page with jQuery's styling.
- I have prepared it for offline loading. I packed the required assets 
  into a folder and in the index.html I reference these assets relatively (e.g. `href="web/styles.css"`).
- If I load this page in my desktop browser, without connectivity, **it
  works**.
- If I load this page in my mobile browser (Chrome or the internal
  one), **it works**.
- If I load this page **without** the assets references in my webview, 
  **it works** (without styling or images, etc.)
- If I load this page **with** the assets reference in my webview, it
  does not work, it's stuck with the spinning wheel. Connectivity does not affect the issue.
- If I remove the line that references the jQM stylesheet, then the page is
  loaded without its styling, but images are loaded properly (so the
  reference to the assets **is** correct)

Note that the spinning wheel shouldn't even be appearing in the first place since I completely disabled AJAX in jQM using:

```
<script>
$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
</script>
```

The odd thing is that AFAIK the internal Android web browser and webviews share the same renderer, so I'm lost as to what could be happening here, and since it works okay with regular browsers, I can debug what's happening.

For reference, this is how I define my webView:

```
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings s = mWebView.getSettings();
    s.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

I had a bunch of other settings but for the sake of simplifying the problem I removed them and the issue persists.

Any suggestions?

PD. As requested, posting the index.html file. This is the simplest example, just an empty index. The problem persists:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=es>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="yes">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320" />
<head>
<title>
    My title
</title>

<script>
$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
</script>

<script src="script/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="script/jquery/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css"  />


</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show code of index.html

Comment: just posted a reduced version, where the problem still exists

Comment: I just found out that commenting out the jQM css line makes the page load (but without styling, obviously), so it seems this is a css related problem

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Solved it myself. Turns out from JellyBean on, the webView settings include a property to disable loading from file resources, and it is disabled by default.

Running my app from a pre-Jelly device works fine, but the two devices I was using for development were both 4.3 based.

I solved it using the following code, if anyone is interested:

```
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
        s.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        s.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    }
```

Comment: I can't find this using API 12 to run on JellyBean... how do you made this work on pre-Jelly using pré Jelly API? Thanks.

Comment: In my case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390985/android-4-0-1-breaks-webview-html-5-local-storage

Comment: It works perfectly. I was only  s.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true), and it works until Android 5.1. I was getting cracy. This s.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true) saved my live! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using `WebView.pauseTimers()`.

Or try `WebView.resumeTimers()` when the Activity which contains the WebView calls `onResume()`.

Answer (score 0):

A big thanks to Gabriel Sanmartin. I had a similar situation but I was using the regular jQuery, not mobile, and calling the .load() function to load a local partial html file into a div, like so:

```
var divNew = document.createElement('div');
var $divNew = $(divNew);
var sFilePath = sSubfolder + '/' + 'Index.html';
$divNew.load(sFilePath, function (response, status, xhr) {
    if (status == "error") {

    }
});
```

I spent almost half a day going thru & debugging the JS code until I came upon this thread. Finding those two settings was fantastic. It made all the difference. My C# code is below:

```
if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.JellyBean)
{
      wbView.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;
      wbView.Settings.AllowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true;
}
```

Fyi:
Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.JellyBean was recommended as Android.OS.Build.VERSION_CODES.JellyBean is obsolete and will be removed in future versions.