# Android WebView JQuery Mobile Page Load Issue

Tags: android, jquery, asp.net, jquery-mobile, webview

I am using a WebView in my android app to load a JQuery Ajax mobile website.

However, I have an issue that when I click any link in the website within the app, the current page refreshes twice before navigating to the next page.

Please note this does not happen when I disable the AJAX on pages navigation.

Also, the site works fine in a normal mobile Browser.

This is my code:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());    
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.myjquerymobilesite.com");
```

Appreciate your help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There were changes in WebView from JB on. Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379392/jquery-mobile-not-working-in-webview-when-loading-from-local-assets) would help..

```
  if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){ 
        s.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true); 
        s.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true); 
    }
```