# Loading an XML file from SD card in jQuery Function

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, android-sdcard

i am trying to read an XML from SD card in jQuery function .. the html file is loaded in webView of android device...here is what i am trying

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#dvContent").append("<ul></ul>");
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "file:///mnt/sdcard/RegInfo/output/data.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml){
    $(xml).find('Book').each(function(){
      var sName = $(this).find('Name').text();
      var sEmail = $(this).find('Email').text();
      $("<li></li>").html(sName + "-" + sEmail).appendTo("#list");
    });
  },
  error: function() {
    alert("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
  }
  });
});
</script>
```

there is something wrong with the file url but i am not being able to figure out the problem...
The code is working fine with desktop browser . . .
and i am not using **PhoneGAp.js** or **Cordova.js**

Comment: what am i doing!!! need my eyes examined. :) sorry WEBVIEW. ill have a look at my notes, and get back if i spot anything

Comment: According to this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379392/jquery-mobile-not-working-in-webview-when-loading-from-local-assets  ---   check your build version, it may be the same issue, it was solved by adding   ---
 if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
        s.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        s.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    }   ----  not sure were he added that code though.

Comment: yeah i did looked at this but in my case its android 2.2

Comment: Using the simulator did you get any errors from the console?

Comment: no errors.. i can even access this file via mobile browser with this link file:///mnt/sdcard/RegInfo/output/data.xml