# Issue on to populate WebView in Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-webview

I am writing an application to launch webView in my activity. But it was launched in web browser.

I refer the [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561709/opening-webview-not-in-new-browser) and [this tutorial too](http://www.androidaspect.com/2012/09/android-webview-tutorial.html)

But When i used `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`, i can get only blank screen.

For that issue i refered [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577698/opening-new-android-activity-with-a-webview-shows-a-blank-white-screen-instead?rq=1)

But no one help in my case..

I have given my code.

Please note what mistake I have done?

My code is:

webview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" >
    </WebView>

</LinearLayout>
```

WebViewActivity.java

```
public class webViewActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;
    private String strUrl;
    public final String TAG = "webViewActivity";
    ProgressBar progBar;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        strUrl = bundle.getString("URL");
        Log.d(TAG, "link is " + strUrl);
        // strUrl = "www.google.com";
        webView = new WebView(this);
        webView.loadUrl(strUrl);

        // progBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progWeb);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                view.loadUrl(strUrl);
                return true;
            }
        });
}
```

Please help to corect my mistake.

Thank you in Advance!!

Comment: you mean you get a white screen when webview is loaded is it correct?

Comment: Ya obsolutely correct.

Comment: ok then you just try setting the background color of webview to zero

Comment: like this webView.setBackgroundColor(0);

Comment: hey,I tried your code the problem is with dynamic calling of webview check that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    <WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" >
   </WebView>
```

In your activity you need to find the id of the webview.

```
webView = new WebView(this);
```

You are creating a webview but you are not adding the same to your layout

You have already defined webview in your xml so there is no need to create the same again. Find the id of the webview and load the url accordingly.

```
   setContentView(R.layout.webview);
   webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);// you need to find the id of webview
   Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
   strUrl = bundle.getString("URL");      
   webView.loadUrl(strUrl);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            view.loadUrl(strUrl);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Make sure you have added internet permission in manifest file

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Check the Edit 2 in the below link for the working sample

[Enable back button in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152491/enable-back-button-in-webview/16152530#16152530)

Comment: Thank you for your worthy reply.. It works fine.. Actually, I already tried with  "webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);", It didn't work. But i used your code. I have recognized that the change is, putting  tools:context=".webViewActivity" this line in .xml file. Thank you so much.

Comment: Sure.. I have a doubt. If i want progress bar to show loading means, Have i use progressbar in xml itself or using "requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);" this is enough?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331094/how-to-add-a-progress-bar-in-webview. Check the link and the accepted answer. Also check the developer site http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code the problem is with dynamic calling of webview check that.
You haven't used

```
          setContentView(webView);
```

Try this ...

Comment: I already used setContentView(R.layout.webview) na? Where will i put this?

Comment: @kavya there is no need to create a webview like webview wv= new WebView(this); he already has a webview in xml and he has set the content of the same.